# IIS Reset itself make request to crash

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, iis, iis-7

We have a WCF service exposed, which fetches lot of static parameters when it first initializesess.
The issue we are facing now is Daily at some random interval our IIS resets itself as a result of whoich
client gets exception.

Is there any reason why this happens and should not it happen seamlessly and how to tackle it?

Answer (score 0):

Here can you read up how recycling works:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525803(v=vs.90).aspx

Here is how you can schedule when the pool should recycle:
http://technet.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/cc754494(v=ws.10).aspx

That might fix you issue in the short run!

In the long run you should write the service so that is can recycle without affecting the consumers of the service. If your service depends on state, then persist that state outside the memory of your service. A distributed cache (like redis) or a database can be an option (depends on what data you are serving).